# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys ). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code for mapping

```
{this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => {
  const showbutton = node.className === "square";
  const decisionbutton = node.className === "diamond";
  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      className={"node " + node.className}
      id={node.id}
      ref={nodes => (this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes)}
      style={node.style}
      onClick={this.activeElem}
    >
      <li key={index}>{node.text}</li>
      {showbutton ? (
        <div
          className="add-btn"
          onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}
        >
          +
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p />
      )}

      {decisionbutton ? (
        <div
          className="add-btn"
          onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}
        >
          +
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p />
      )}
      <div
        className="delete-btn"
        onClick={event => this.deleteNode(event, node)}
      >
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

This is the output which I got in the console:

[image: console output]

https://gyazo.com/ed186244e0049b42c4bd751e02c9fc73

Basically I want to render the text which is like this:

> Node which is mapped from Node state text array inside text node state
>   and inside text array

```
node>>>text[]>>text[]
```

I want to access the last text.
Please check my screenshot for better understanding the problem I am facing.
Thanks in advance brother !

Comment: @Tholle brother please help me with this!!!

Comment: `node.text` is an array which has an object with text prop which is an array. So if you need to access the text 'c' you will have to do `{node.text[0].text[0]}`. If you want to access 'as', you will need `{node.text[0].text[1]}.` That's a really awful structure in my humble opinion.